# Difference between `StringJoin` and `StringExpression`

Tags: string-manipulation, function-comparison

When does one need `StringJoin` as opposed to `StringExpression`? I don't know of an example where `s1<>s2<>...<>sn` works but `s1~~s2~~...~~sn` does not.

Comment: From [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html) "StringExpression is closely related to StringJoin, except nonstrings are allowed and lists are not flattened. For pure strings, they are equivalent."

Comment: Generally, you should consider `StringJoin` as on operation for joining strings together, while `StringExpression` is meant for pattern matching strings when using functions like `StringCases`, `StringMatchQ` and `StringPosition`. A `StringExpression` is much more like a regular expression in that sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @Jason B's comment, `StringJoin` can handle (and flattens) lists.

`StringJoin[{"Ab", "cd"}, {"ef"}]` returns `Abcdef`, whereas `StringExpression[{"Ab", "cd"}, {"ef"}]` returns `{"Ab", "cd"} ~~ {"ef"}`.

Comment: But it works too, `StringCases[ "bf", {"b", "d"} ~~ {"f"}]`, so what works better? :)