# Replace number in string with ? and /;

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am trying to make the following:

```
StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x_ -> "B" ~~ x}]
```

This should replace `A4` by `B4` but leave `A#3` untouched. How can I do that? I tried to use `?` and `/;` with a test for whether or not the `_` is a number string as follows:

```
StringReplace[{"A4","A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x_?StringMatchQ[x_, NumberString] -> "B" ~~ x}]
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know how to make the syntax work for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've mixed up the usage of `PatternTest` (`?`) and `Condition` (`/;`). Here're 4 approaches, please read the document carefully to understand why they work:

```
StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x_?(StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &) :> "B" <> x}]
(* {"B4", "A#3"} *)

StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString]) :> "B" <> x}]
(* {"B4", "A#3"} *)

StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, NumberString] :> "B" <> x}]
(* {"B4", "A#3"} *)

StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x : NumberString :> "B" <> x}]
(* {"B4", "A#3"} *)
```

### Remark

1. Though `StringExpression` (`~~`) can be used in right hand side (RHS) of a rule, I've used `StringJoin` (`<>`) instead in code above because it's a better choice. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250014/1871) and [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100423/1871) for more info.
2. I've used `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`), because the RHS of rule cannot be evaluated immediately when `<>` is used instead of `~~`.
3. Even if `~~` is used in the RHS of rule, `:>` is still a better choice for your problem. Just try the following sample:

   ```
   x = 123;
   StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x : NumberString -> "B" ~~ x}]
   (* {"B" ~~ 123, "A#3"} *)

   StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, {"A" ~~ x : NumberString :> "B" ~~ x}]
   (* {"B4", "A#3"} *)
   ```

Comment: When we apply `(StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &`, this works like a function applied in `x_`? It's as if it were `(StringMatchQ[x_, NumberString]`? The syntax looks so weird to me, we are calling the "variable" `x_` and then telling it to apply this "function" callling it something else, namely `#`.

Comment: @RedBanana Please notice `?` is just a shorthand for `PatternTest`, so `x_?(StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &)` is equivalent to `PatternTest[x_, StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &]`. In other words,  `PatternTest` is a function whose first argument is a **pattern** and last argument is a **function relationship** that will be used to test the expression matching the pattern in first argument. The design is somewhat similar to `Select`, `NestWhile`, etc., you can compare them.

Comment: @RedBanana Ah I've made an improper statement about `StringExpression` (`~~`), it can actually be used in right hand side of rule. But still, `StringJoin` is a better choice, see the new-added links.

Answer (score 4):

In this case maybe consider a `RegularExpression`

```
StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, RegularExpression["(A)(\\d)"] :> "B$2"]

(* {"B4", "A#3"} *)
```

Or even(!)

```
StringReplace[{"A4", "A#3"}, RegularExpression["(A)(\\d)"] :> 
    FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["$1"] + 1] <> "$2"]

(* {"B4", "A#3"} *)
```